# Is there any vectorial form of Ceva theorem

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle. $X, Y, Z$ on the side $BC, CA, AB$ respectively. Then the famous Ceva theorem claims that $AX, BY, CZ$ are concurrent if and only if $\dfrac{BX}{XC}\cdot\dfrac{YC}{YA}\cdot \dfrac{AZ}{ZB}=1$ (for simplicity I omit the algebraic length here).

My question is, have we got any vectorial form of Ceva theorem with the condition on three vectors $AX, BY, CZ$ to be concurrent? Like: $AX, BY, CZ$ are concurrent if and only if $\overrightarrow{AX}; \overrightarrow{BY};\overrightarrow{CZ}....$

Comment: Because the vectors are base-point-independent, there is no hope for such a formula that only depends on the vectors.